# Google reCaptcha json response return false

Tags: php, json, recaptcha

I have tried google captcha using PHP as following way

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf2yUUUAAksikja1XQNtIOqIDmtzb46uHGY-Wq_sl">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $secret = '6Lf2yUAAHvAr2QoaNHYFDG945Z6Ai7EqTg6Y71';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret=&response=" . rawurlencode($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) . "&remoteip=" . rawurlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if($responseData->success){

    } else {
      echo 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    }
}
```

This same code has worked in PHP 5.4 But Is not working on PHP 7.0 , i don't know how to fix it, any suggestion or solution please post

Comment: What error/warning are you getting right now in PHP 7.0?

Comment: success false
challenge_ts "2018-02-12T07:16:22Z"    \n  0 "timeout-or-duplicate" @Amit Merchant

Comment: one more thing my old server PHP Version is 5.5 but now i have to move my doamin as another server it has PHP 7.0 just i am guessing may be this was PHP Version compatability issue

Comment: The code you have used for verification is perfectly compatible for PHP 7 and PHP 5.5

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way.
    Hope it will help you.

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
  $privatekey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $data = array(
      'secret' => $privatekey,
      'response' => $captcha,
      'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
  );

  $curlConfig = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $jsonResponse = json_decode($response);
  if ($jsonResponse->success === true) {

  }
  else {
      $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
    }
} else{

  $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get `timeout-or-duplicate` issue if your captcha is validated twice. Save logs in a file in append mode and check if you are validating a Captcha twice.

For instance, check below:

```
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])

file_put_contents( "logfile",  $verifyResponse, FILE_APPEND );
```

Now, check the logfile created above and try to check if captcha is verified twice.

Comment: $verifyResponse return empty . logfile is empty@Amit Merchant

Comment: try adding extension (for eg. `.txt`) to the log file and check again.